# Trouble in finding examples of a boolean ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example of a finite and infinite Boolean ring without unity.

I find difficulty to answer this question.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391169/do-boolean-rings-always-have-a-unit-element

Comment: But @Rohan I don't find any finite Boolean ring without unity in the link you provided.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay read the answers.  For example, the top answer: *An example: the family of all finite subsets of a given infinite set*

Comment: But @Omnomnomnom is this family finite?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay Sorry, I kept missing the word "finite" somehow.  If you read Martin's answer, you'll see that *every finite boolean ring is unital*, so there are no finite examples.

Comment: Since the linked question addresses all the questions here, closing as dupe